# Modifying Key in hash table?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I was just wondering if you can modify the key in a hashtable. I have been able to successfully modify the value attached to the key but have been unable to modify the actually key.

```powershell
$names = @{Tree = "1"; Forest = "2"}
```

Take for example the code above, I'd like to change the `"Tree"` to something other than tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot do this directly.  Instead, 
you will need to make a *new* key that has the same value as `"Tree"` and then delete the `"Tree"` key when you are done.  Below is a demonstration:

```powershell
PS > $names = @{Tree = "1"; Forest = "2"}
PS > $names.NewKey = $names.Tree
PS > $names.Remove("Tree")
PS > $names

Name                           Value                                                
----                           -----                                                
NewKey                            1                                                    
Forest                            2                                                    


PS >
```

Comment: I suppose the answer to the question then is, "no, you can't modify a key, you have to do something else to simulate the effect". :)

Comment: Makes since, just making sure. I figured you couldn't but I also figured I'd ask! Thanks!